# maven local repository contains 2 paths for oracle dependency

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc, dependencies, pom.xml

So for some unknown reasons I have 2 local dependencies for oracle: "\com\oracle\jdbc\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2" and "\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2".
In pom.xml I have this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As a result the project does not run due to missing artifact com.oracle.jdbc.
What is the root cause of this problem?

Comment: Apparently you installed it twice under two different names, other than that we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Download the official version 12.1.0.2 of ojdbc7.jar from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html


Then open a command prompt in the directory where this file is located, and run this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle.jdbc -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This will install the driver into the local repository in proper subdirectory, that is:

```
<maven-local-repo-root>\com\oracle\jdbc\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2
```

Next, refresh your project and the dependency should be visible in the project.

Comment: I removed the files from com\oracle\ojdbc and refreshed the project. the problem is that the error log now shows "Invalid ZIP archive: C:\Users\A\.m2\repository\com\oracle\jdbc\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar"

Comment: could this problem be cause by file in my project still points to the previous directory(the one without jdbc) or may be another project is referencing the old directory?